# Setting node.PropertiesAsList as Datasource for a repeater

Tags: c#, datasource, repeater, umbraco

I'm trying to set the PropertiesList of a node as the DataSource for my repeater.

```
rptDistributors.DataSource = node.PropertiesAsList;
rptDistributors.DataBind();
```

And in my repeater I try to get the umbDistributorCountry.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDistributors" runat="server">
  <%# Eval("umbDistributorCountry") %>
</asp:Repeater>
```

However I run into problems because it doesn't know any of the properties.

> DataBinding: 'umbraco.NodeFactory.Property' does not contain a property with the name 'umbDistributorCountry'.

The content of the list looks like the following:

[image: property list]

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Where exactly does it throw this error? I am guessing during the actual binding (ie: `rptDistributor.DataBind()`) ? Is that correct?

Comment: Not on that method, it's in the HTML of the repeater that it throws the error.

Comment: I would guess it's not the optimal answer, but can you reference the properties by their index? Going off your screenshot, you can reference "umbDistributorCountry" with "9". Would this statify your requirements? Or, write a extension method for `PropertiesAsList` that accepts the Alias "umbDistributorCountry" and returns the value? If any of these seem workable for you, let me know and I will be happy to provide some sample code.

Comment: Yeah the index would be fine for me, but I wouldn't know how to get that value in the repeater. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: No problem. Go ahead and post your markup code for the repeater and I'll whip up some code for you.

Comment: It's just a simple repeater; `<asp:Repeater ID="rptDistributors" runat="server"> <%# Eval("umbDistributorCountry") %> </asp:Repeater>`, but that obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Taking another look at your code, it looks like you are binding the a single node to the Repeater. A Repeater is for binding multiple items of the same type. Do you see the problem here?

Comment: I do yes, I will take a look at it tomorrow. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error ...

> DataBinding: 'umbraco.NodeFactory.Property' **does not contain a property** with the name 'umbDistributorCountry'.

`umbDistributorCountry` is not a **.NET property**, but the value of the property called `Alias`. An **Umbraco property** contains the three **.NET properties** in your screenshot, so you only have access to these ...

```html
<%# Eval("Alias") %>
<%# Eval("Value") %>
<%# Eval("Version") %>
```

Assuming you want to show all the **Umbraco properties** of that particular distributor (which is stored in `node`, I guess), you would need something like this ....

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDistributors" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Alias") %> : <%# Eval("Value") %> <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```